# Reference type dependency - declare Map.Entry to be dependent on generic types declared for TreeMap

Tags: java, oop, generics, dependencies, treemap

let's imagine this scenario - I would like to use TreeMap in java. It's part of the Colletions framework and the only implementation of the SortedMap interface.

```
public class MyDictionary extends TreeMap<String, String> {
// some code
}
```

In order to walk through the entries stored in my Dictionary class I will need a type of Map.Entry. Somewhere in the code (could be a method of the MyDictionary class or even more likely a method in the wrapper class containing a variable of MyDictionary class holding my data) there will be something like:

```
public void showEntries() {
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : dictionary) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey(), e.getValue());  // do something
  }
}
```

And now the question: **is there a way to bind the generic types of Map.Entry to the generic types declared for the TreeMap?**

The goal is to have the generic types defined in one place only.

In case I decide to change the type of data held in the TreeMap later I won't have to search all places where I used those types.

The example above is a Proof-Of-Concept. Pls help.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `MyDictionary` class generic, with type parameters to match `TreeMap`.

```
public class MyDictionary<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, V>
```

Then you can refer to those type parameters throughout your class.  Specifically:

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : dictionary) {
```

Or if you know that the key and the value will always be the same type:

```
public class MyDictionary<E> extends TreeMap<E, E>
```

and

```
for (Map.Entry<E, E> e : dictionary) {
```

Comment: thank you for the post, my problem is that I do not know in advance which walk-throughs will be necessary so using methods of the MyDictionary itself is a suboptimal solution - pls see my comments and explanation below as per @Marcin 's post who is a bit closer

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using two adapters - one for Entry and one for Iterator.

First, inside Dictionary, you create your Entry adapter, e.g.:

```
public static class Entry implements Map.Entry<String, String> {
  private Map.Entry<String, String> entry;

  Entry(Map.Entry<String, String> entry) {
    this.entry = entry;
  }

  @Override
  public String getKey() {
    return entry.getKey();
  }

  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    return entry.getValue();
  }

  @Override
  public String setValue(String value) {
    return entry.setValue(value);
  }
}
```

To be able to use your Dictionary class in the foreach loop, you have to implement Iterable interface. TreeMap does not implement it.

```
public class Dictionary extends TreeMap<String, String> implements Iterable<Dictionary.Entry>
```

You can write your iterator() method like this:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Entry> iterator() {
  return new Iterator<Entry>() {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> wrapped = entrySet().iterator();

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return wrapped.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Entry next() {
      return new Entry(wrapped.next());
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      wrapped.remove();
    }
  };
}
```

Now, you can enjoy using foreach loops without generic types:

```
for (Dictionary.Entry e : dictionary) {
  System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
}
```

Comment: thank you, Marcin, this seems a pretty robust approach, you are very close. The problem is as follows - typically when a TreeMap is needed (or similar) it is because of its methods such as entrySet(), floorEntry(), firstEntry(), headMap()...etc that return different subsets of the complete mapping set. Usually a full walkthrough is not performed on the object but on the results returned by the above mentioned methods.

Comment: what happens now is that `for (Dictionary.Entry e : en2de.entrySet()) {}` I still receive _Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Map.Entry<String,String> to Dictionary.Entry_ Pls note that the variable en2de is of type Dictionary;

Comment: does anyone have a good proposal (except for overriding all those TreeMap methods... :-) ?